# Web API methods with lots of parameters

Tags: http, http-post, asp.net-web-api, http-get

I am working on a Web API service for our Web application (current project). One controller in the Web API will be responsible to retrieve a list of entities of a certain type. So far so good. The problem is that we have a request to filter the list based on search criteria. This search/filter criteria has about a dozen different parameters, some of which can be null. So I figured I create a custom class (let's call it "EntityFilterCriteria") and I instantiate it on the Web application side with whatever filtering fields the user enters (I leave the ones that the user do not enter set to null). Now how do I pass this object to my Web API method? I do not want to build an URL with all parameters because it's going to be a huge URL, plus some parameters may be missing. I can't have a body in the GET HTTP command to serialize my EntityFilterCriteria object so what do I use? POST? It is not really a POST because nothing is updated on the server side. It is really a GET, as in "get me all the records that match this search criteria". What is the common approach in such situations?

Thanks,
Eddie

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the class to JSON and post it to your server, the JSON string will be your post body.  Once it is posted you can then deserialize into a class with the same signature.  Most languages have either built-in support or free 3rd party modules that can do this for you.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. I appreciate you comment. Two of the same opinion pretty much settled it for me. POST it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well the initial danger of using GET for such a request is that the longest url you can send which is guarenteed to work across all web browsers and servers is about 1400 bytes in length.

Personally I would use JSON to encode all of your filter parameters and submit them to the server in the body of a POST command due to the lack of size limit on the sent data.

While there is a semantic difference between GET and POST commands which was intentioned when the HTTP RFC's were written decades ago, those decades of practical use have shifted rather significantly (in the same way that barely anybody uses PUT or DELETE)

Comment: Thank you, Damian. You seem to be in accord with Jon's answer further below. I will do a POST.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any drawbacks to use a POST method to execute your query and get the result back. For example, ElasticSearch uses this approach to execute queries against the database. See this link for example: http://exploringelasticsearch.com/searching_data.html. In REST, POST isn't necessary used to update data.

Hope it helps.
Thierry